# Umlaut in alphabetic citation keys in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

My citation organisation tool of choice (so far) exports umlauts like `ö` as `\"{o}`. When these occur in the beginning of the first author's name of a bib entry, the citation shorthand is generated from the letters before the umlaut and with the dots above the first number of the year.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lib.bib}
@book{Goethe1773,
    author = {von G\"{o}the, JW},
    title = {Götz von Berlichingen},
    year = {1773}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}

\begin{document}

In~\cite{Goethe1773}...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I change the `\"{o}` manually to `{\"o}`, the shorthand is consistent with the others (`Göt73`), when I change it to `ö` itself, it becomes `Gö73` (without t).

Can I get `Göt73` without manually editing each umlaut-containing bib entry each time I export my library? (With biber as backend this is what I get in all three cases, however, there are other problems with my library.)

Comment: Well as it works fine with biber: solve whatever problem you have with this backend. bibtex expects the other input and doesn't handle utf8 correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the name spelled "Goethe"?! To me, "Göthe" looks plain awful.

Comment: Using `ö` instead of `\"{o}` works fine for me, using `latexmk` in MiKTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the specific example can be better solved using the correct spelling for the name, which is *Goethe*, but I'll assume that this choice was deliberate in order not to mention any specific real case.

---

The correct syntax with BibTeX is

```
G{\"{o}}the
```

[image]

There's *nothing* you can do about it, except fixing the entries.

On the other hand, if you use Biber, you can type either

```
G\"othe
```

or

```
Göthe
```

Here's an example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goethe1773,
    author = {von G{\"{o}}the, JW},
    title = {Götz von Berlichingen},
    year = {1773}
}
@book{Goethe1773x,
    author = {von G\"othe, JW},
    title = {Götz von Berlichingen},
    year = {1773}
}
@book{Goethe1773y,
    author = {von Göthe, JW},
    title = {Götz von Berlichingen},
    year = {1773}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

In~\cite{Goethe1773}, in \cite{Goethe1773x}
and in \cite{Goethe1773y}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you examine the `.bbl` file, you'll find a difference between the three items: in the first the author turns out to be `G{ö}the`, which *may* be relevant as far as collation is concerned, but a rough test seems to reveal it isn't.

Comment: Doesn't the question already mention Biber (and rule it out)?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I added the Biber example and pointed out that there's nothing to do when BibTeX is used.

Comment: Thinking about down-voting this answer and any others that mis-spell "Goethe" as "Göthe", or "G{\"o}the", or some other variant that generates an Umlaut...

Comment: @Mico I guess that the OP wanted to deliberately use a wrongly spelled name, so not to point to any specific real case. I added some words about this to my answer. By the way, in these days I'm reading “Italienische Reise” (in Italian translation).

Comment: It would have been nice if the OP had had the decency to use "Gödel" as the name for these trials...

Comment: "There's nothing you can do about it". Thank you for the clarification, and sorry for not thinking of "Gödel" for the example.